# Unity 2d C# перетаскивание с поворотом

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я до сих пор плохо понимаю C#. но у меня есть идея игры, которую я хочу сделать.

У меня есть объект квадрата. Мне нужно, чтобы его можно было перетаскивать мышкой, но при этом он вращался в зависимости от того, за какую точку он был взят.

Я также хочу понять, как сделать невозможным перемещение его через коллайдер с помощью мыши.

Я видел подобную механику в нескольких играх. Самый знакомый мне пример — people playground.